# Using induction to prove $2^{n-1}(1 + a_1a_2\ldots a_n) \geq (1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots(1+a_n)$ for $a_i \geq 1$

Tags: inequality, induction

Hello I have been blasting at this inequality proof and it is just not doing what I want it to do:

> Prove that $2^{n-1}(a_1a_2\ldots a_n + 1) \geq (1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots(1+a_n)$ assuming that $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n \geq 1$.$\:\:\:$

So the base case is pretty trivial, which leads me to assume that this inequality holds for $k$, so I want to prove $P(k+1)$. I do the following:

$$
(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots(1+a_k)(1+a_{k+1})\leq 2^{k-1}(a_1a_2\ldots a_k + 1)(a_{k+1} + 1) 
$$
I tried methods like setting the second "$1$" to $a_{k+1}$ and then I have $2^k(a_1\ldots a_k + 1)a_{k+1}$ but I can't assume from there that $2^k(a_1...a_ka_{k+1} +a_{k+1})$ and the second $a_{k+1}$ becomes $1$. So maybe my method is not good from the get-go. Thank you!

Comment: Do the $n=2$ case separately, and then use that in the induction step.

Comment: Not very helpful, but you can rewrite the inequality to a more symmetric form: $$\frac{1 + a_1 a_2 \dots a_n}{2} \geq \left(\frac{1 + a_1}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1 + a_2}{2}\right) \dots \left(\frac{1 + a_n}{2}\right).$$ In other words, the function $f(x) = \frac{1 + x}{2}$ satisfies $f(x) f(y) \leq f(xy)$ for $x,y \geq 1$.

Comment: @CalvinLin I don't really understand how that will help, so then I know that $(1+a_1)(1+a_2) \leq 2(a_1a_2 + 1)$ (which is easy to show why it is true) how to use it in the inductive step, do you mean for me to do something like $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots(1+a_k)(1+a_{k+1}) \leq 2(a_1a_2 + 1)(a_3 + 1)\ldots(a_{k+1} + 1)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The inequality is equivalent to: 
$$
\left(\frac{1+a_1}{2}\right)\cdots \left(\frac{1+a_n}{2}\right) \le \left(\frac{1+a_1\cdots a_n}{2}\right)
$$
Assuming the induction hypothesis we want to show:
$$
\left(\frac{1+a_1}{2}\right)\cdots \left(\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{2}\right) \le \left(\frac{1+a_1\cdots a_{n+1}}{2}\right)
$$
It is enough to show:
$$
\left(\frac{1+a_1\cdots a_n}{2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{2}\right) \le \left(\frac{1+a_1\cdots a_{n+1}}{2}\right)
$$
Or 
$$
1+a_1\cdots a_n+a_{n+1}+a_1\cdots a_{n+1} \le 2(1+a_1\cdots a_{n+1})
$$
enough to show
$$
a_1\cdots a_n + a_{n+1} \le 1+a_1\cdots a_{n+1}
$$
Or
$$
a_{n+1}-1\le (a_{n+1}-1)a_1\cdots a_n
$$
or just $1\le a_1\cdots a_n$.

Comment: Oh wow that is a pretty cool proof! Thank you @Tao, for a split second though I thought you were terence tao :P ... anyway thank you very much!

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I followed your induction strategy. Starting from:
$$(1+a_1)\dots(1+a_{k+1})\le 2^{k-1}(a_1\dots a_k+1)(a_{k+1}+1)$$
Let's take $A = a_1 \dots a_k$. $$2^{k-1}(a_1\dots a_k+1)(a_{k+1}+1)=2^{k}(A.a_{k+1} + 1)+2^{k-1}(A-A.a_{k+1}-1+a_{k+1})$$
The first part of the right formula is what we want. We have to prove that the second part is negative to prove $P(k+1)$.

That part can be rewritten $2^{k-1}(A-A.a_{k+1}-1+a_{k+1})=2^{k-1}(A-1)(1-a_{k+1})\le 0$ because $a_{k+1} \ge 1$ and $A \ge 1$. So finally,
$$(1+a_1)\dots(1+a_{k+1})\le 2^{k}(a_1\dots a_{k+1}+1)$$